# How to change Carbon Design System Icon Size? React

Tags: reactjs, websphere, carbon-design-system

I'm not finding any way to change Icon size on the IBM Carbon Design System

```
<Icon size='16px'/> ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/guidelines/icons/code/#usage

> Icons in this package support the following sizes: 16, 20, 24, and 32
> pixels. These sizes refer to the width and height of the icon. You can
> import an icon component into your project by referring to its name
> and size:

```
import { Add24 } from '@carbon/icons-react';
```

Meaning, you should try import the icon with the size you wish to use. In the example above, they are using the 24px version of `Add` icon so they import `Add24`

Comment: I take error when import Add24, but I dont take any error in importing Add icon

Answer (score 0):

While adrian's answer was right for Carbon v10, this has changed for v11. Now you can change the icon size by doing the following:

```
<Add size={24}/>
```

You can read more about it here https://carbondesignsystem.com/migrating/guide/develop/#@carbonicons-react